# Prediction returning nan

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to make a `TensorFlow` regression model. I also try to run this on the GPU, change activations to `relu`, `tanh`, `sigmoid`, change optimizers SGD, but it still returning `nan`. Is there a problem with this code?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Dataset=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
Dataset_droped = Dataset.drop(["PassengerId", "Name", "Ticket"], axis=1)
Dataset_one_hot = pd.get_dummies(Dataset_droped)

X = Dataset_one_hot.drop(["Survived"], axis=1)
y = Dataset_one_hot["Survived"]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

tf.random.set_seed(42)
model_10 = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model_10.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
metrics=['accuracy'])

history_10 = model_10.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)

model_10.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like your model is exploding the gradient as it is returning the nan values.

- also, please check if you return the sequence from the Dense layer to the next layer.
- try to add drop out layer in between and see how the training goes
- change and specify the activation layer into sigmoid since your target is binary, its look like there is no activation function defined.

find the link for Dense: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense